# Problem enabling the traceSip option in the Sip.js javascript framework

Tags: sip

I have a small issue related to the Sip.js framework for SIP Calling.
The problem is that I am unable to enable the traceSip parameter inspite of setting it to true as specified in the configuration.
The console in Chrome browser shows the value of the 'traceSip' parameter as false. I am trying to set it to true

I cannot post to Sip.js mailing list as they require the log with this option to be attached to the post which I am unable to do

Please find attached my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-styles.css">

<script language="javascript" src="js/sip-0.11.6.min.js"></script>

<script>
var session; // aglobal variable for the user session
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
var localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');

//registration
var userAgent = new SIP.UA({
  uri: 'test1@10.10.30.10',
  transportOptions: {
    wsServers: ['ws://10.10.30.10:8090']
  },
  authorizationUser: 'test1',
  password: '****',  
  traceSip: true,
  iceCheckingTimeout: 35000,
  register: true,
  stunServers: [],
  turnServers: []

});

function createUserSession(userName,userAgent)
{
    //send invitation
var session = userAgent.invite(userName, {
    media: {
        constraints: {
            audio: true,
            video: false
        }
    }
});

return session;
}
//create the user session
function callUser()
{
    session=createUserSession(document.getElementById('txtUserName').value,userAgent);
    //alert('Session created' + session.remoteIdentity);

}

//accept invitation

userAgent.on('invite', function(session) {
  alert('incoming call');
  session.accept();

});

//add media event
session.on('trackAdded', function() {
  // We need to check the peer connection to determine which track was added

  var pc = session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection;

  // Gets remote tracks
  var remoteStream = new MediaStream();
  pc.getReceivers().forEach(function(receiver) {
    remoteStream.addTrack(receiver.track);
  });
  remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
  remoteVideo.play();

  // Gets local tracks
  var localStream = new MediaStream();
  pc.getSenders().forEach(function(sender) {
    localStream.addTrack(sender.track);
  });
  localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
  localVideo.play();
});

function endCall()
{
    session.terminate();
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>

    fsdfsafd
    <video id="remoteVideo"></video>
    <video id="localVideo" muted="muted"></video>
    <input type='text' id='txtUserName' value='test@10.10.30.10'/>
    <button id="endCall" onclick="javascript:endCall();">End Call</button>
    <button id="callUser" onclick="callUser();">CAll User</button>



  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Mathew

Answer (score 0):

traceSip has to be added to the transportOptions section as below

```
var userAgent = new SIP.UA({
  uri: 'test@test.local',
  transportOptions: {
    wsServers: ['ws://10.10.30.10:8090'],
    traceSip: true,
    iceCheckingTimeout: 35000,
    register: true,
    stunServers: [],
    turnServers: []
  },
  authorizationUser: 'test',
  password: '****'
});
```